# How to reset GDM3 configuration

Tags: gnome, login, gdm

I saw maybe on Reddit on r/Ubuntu or maybe on r/gnome about a Flatpak to customize the GDM/login/greeter. I installed it, took a look, and decided I was not very interested and just uninstalled it. It's this here https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.realmazharhussain.GdmSettings . I believe I didn't change anything, BUT....

Now my PC boots and goes to a blinking cursor

I can press alt+F2, the tty session shows up, I can login there and the system is fully functional from the command line, just something on that app broke to gdm3.

I can check the /etc/gdm3 files with nano, use sudo and I execute the gdm3 binary installed. Attempts to use xinit or xstart lead to another tty session stuck with a blinking cursor or error messages.

Executing 'systemctl status gdm' I get:
Gdm': Child process -2185 was already dead
GdmDisplay: Session never registered
Gdm-launch-environmemt GLib-Gobject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

The system is pretty default, just Ubuntu, Gnome, maybe 3 plugins.
Ubuntu 22.10
kernel 5.19.0-35
gdm3 --version is 43.0

(Of course cannot ctrl+c ctrl-v all the messages due to tty only)

Now the question: how can I reset the configuration files for it, or at least look up the default files to compare and copy?

Thank!

Comment: Perhaps re-find the guide, figure out what it does, and undo it? Look at the files in /etc, and sort by date to see which ones you touched most recently?

Comment: @popey updated the post with the link . It's not a guide but a GUI app

Comment: Perhaps file an issue with that project, if you believe it broke your setup? https://github.com/realmazharhussain/gdm-settings/issues

Comment: @popey it's there https://github.com/realmazharhussain/gdm-settings/discussions/153

Answer (score 0):

As just my luck... It was completely unrelated to Gdm settings application.
I spend hours trying to see what it changed the settings for nothing.

I had earlier installed wireguard (apt install wireguard) and I'm not sure what's up, but it seems that it bring a different kernel, without the proper headers and modules recompilation, I'm not sure super, that's not my area of expertise. But long story short... boot the computer holding shift, go to grub, run the previous kernel, remove the newer kernel, remove wireguard, remove nvidia, re-install nvidia, recompile `dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-` for good measure and it's all working fine.

Now gotta find out where to report this. It's the second time that installing Wireguard messes-up my installation.